# Google Visualization Pie Chart text anchor issue

Tags: google-visualization

I am drawing google pie chart but values cut off. Any suggestion what is going on? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to the labels on the pie slices?  If so, there are a few possible causes: typically, errors of this type are due to improperly loading the API or drawing the chart inside a hidden div.  More recently, there is a bug in Chrome that is causing an alignment issue (this, naturally, will only manifest when viewed in Chrome).  If you update your post with code that reproduces the problem, I will take a look.

Comment: Go to this link http://billboard.aee.net/#searchBills Select any state and then press search bills, you will see there two pie charts, which are cutting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing the charts inside a hidden div (div id "control_search_results" has "disply:none" via class "hidden").  This messes up the dimension detection algorithms in the API, which is why your labels are off.  You need to unhide the div prior to drawing the charts.

Be aware that this will fix the problem in most browsers, but you could still run into a similar issue in Chrome due to the browser bug I mentioned in the comments above.