# Google Visualization Pie Chart text anchor issue and text cut off

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I am using google pie charts, all is working fine but legend label on right side is cut off.[image]

there is also no option in google API to control these labels. here is documentations
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options

for whiteHat
please see here are images..
1st[image: hide-div] with hide div

and a div not hide...

[image: no-hide div]

Comment: is it possible the container elements are not visible when drawn? i've seen similar results...

Comment: ok I tried it also on visible element... NO LUCK

Comment: I have read this thread also..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129082/google-visualization-pie-chart-text-anchor-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the legend would normally wrap, see following working snippet,
using the options shown in the attached image

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Education', 'People'],
      ['less than high school', 10],
      ['high school', 10],
      ['college associate', 10],
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: '470',
      height: '450',
      chartArea: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        left: 100,
      },
      pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: '17.5'
      },
      colors: ['#90c458', '#ff7f66', '#ffce55', '#52c2e8']
    };

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: are you sure the element is visible when drawn? not just the element, but it's parent, all the way up...

Comment: when div is hide, then it has this result
http://i64.tinypic.com/2qv6rfl.png
and when div is hide then it has this result
http://i66.tinypic.com/2qcmkcz.png